# Not able to import module from other directory using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please find my project structure attached as image below

[image]

I'm running jobs/my_job.py from project root directory i.e from sample_project,
when I'm running the jobs/my_job.py using `python .\jobs\my_job.py` getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\jobs\my_job.py", line 1, in <module>
    from dependencies.spark import test
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dependencies'
```

This is the code I'm running

from dependencies.spark import test

```
def main():
    test()
```

Since I'm running the code from root directory, why I'm getting that error?

please find the screen of whole
[image]

Comment: you should put ____init____.py to jobs folder too

Comment: @Ehsan tried but still facing same issue

Comment: if the ‘dependencies’ folder is in the ‘sample_project’ directory, you can change the import statement to the following:

from sample_project.dependencies.spark import test

This will ensure that the ‘dependencies’ folder is visible to the Python interpreter.

Comment: @CoolNetworking, that also didn't work throwing error : no module name sample_project

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add dependencies folder to system paths, because the script you are trying to run locates in another directory.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../dependencies')

from dependencies.spark import test
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```